# How to use control register in more privileged mode?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I am reading this book: [C, Assembly, and Program Execution on Intel® 64 Architecture (Igor Zhirkov)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Low-Level-Programming-Assembly-Execution-Architecture/dp/1484224027).There is listing in chapter about `global descriptot table`:

### A snippet from the book, not real bootloader

*Listing 3-1. Enabling Protected Mode loader_start32.asm*

```
section .text
global start32
start32:
    lgdt cs:[_gdtr]
    mov eax, cr0 ;privileged instruction
    or al, 1 ;bit resposnible for protected mode
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp (0x1 << 3):start32 ;assign first seg selector to cs
    align 16
_gdtr: ;stores GDT's last entry index + GDT address
    dw 47 ; word - 2 bytes
    dq _gdt ; quadword - 8 bytes ... then _gdtr should be 10 bytes long 
    align 16
 _gdt: 
    dd 0x00, 0x00 ; null descriptor
    db 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x9A, 0xCF, 0x00 ;differ by exec bit
    db 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x92, 0xCF, 0x00 ;execution off (0x92)
```

I have several question to this snippet:

1. I know `cr0` - control register is not accessible without privileged, but then, how do I gain them from code in my case (after `lgdt cs:[_gdtr]`)? 
   In Intel doc, the `lgdt` instruction says:

> Loads the values in the source operand into the global descriptor table register (GDTR) or the interrupt descriptor
>   table register (IDTR)

But ther is NO mention about gaining any privileges, so I should be not able to use `cr0` in `mov` instruction.
Therefor, when compiling getting *first* error:
**invalid combination of opcode and operands** (in the row of `mov eax, cr0 ;privileged instruction`)

2. Why did author used `align 16`?
   As far as I know, `align X` should be used in order to make custom memory boundary. So in this case, data should be align 16 bytes long. But, If I looked at the code, I see:

   ```
       _gdtr: ;stores GDT's last entry index + GDT address
       dw 47 ; word - 2 bytes
       dq _gdt ; quadword - 8 bytes ... then _gdtr should be 10 bytes long
   ```

Which, as mentioned in code - is **10 bytes long**, not 16.
So when compiling, getting *second* error:
**64-bit unsigned relocation zero-extended from 32 bits [-w+zext-reloc]**.

3. Moreover, the definition of label `_gdt` is:

   ```
   dd 0x00, 0x00 ; null descriptor
   db 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x9A, 0xCF, 0x00 ;differ by exec bit
   db 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x92, 0xCF, 0x00 ;execution off (0x92)
   ```

That is 2 times double-word (8 bytes) + 8 times byte + 8 times byte. Altogether, the amount is 32 bytes, not 8 (as should be quadword in `dq _gdt ; quadword`).

The last question is also about `align X`

4. How long will the instruction `align X` last?
   in the snippet, it is used twice and in both cases BEFORE label. So does it last only for particular frame of address (label)? If so, then how it will "know" when  the address (label) ends? And after that, it will be default alignment again?

[Additional info for errors]:
Compiled with this flag:
`nasm -felf32 somefile.nasm`

I may added some other flags, to resolve the `align` error for `64-bit unsigned relocation zero-extended from 32 bits [-w+zext-reloc]`.
`

Comment: Real mode doesn't have privilege / ring levels, everything = kernel mode.  If you're writing a 16-bit bootloader, you can execute privileged instructions unless you enter protected mode and jump to an unprivileged code segment.

Comment: Well I suppose, it is not executed in real mode, when it is 'user program' and as header suggest, it is `protected mode loader`, So it should be in 32-bit mode (but us fired from 64 long mode, therefor the flags `-felf32`), where privilege/ring level exists. Otherwise, do not understand your comment.

Comment: Sounds like a bootloader that *enters* protected mode, and can load further code and jump to it in protected mode.  Clearly it's enabling protected mode by setting that bit in CR0.  It wouldn't need to do that if it was supposed to already execute in 16 or 32-bit protected mode, or 64-bit mode.  I mention 64-bit mode becase `dq _gdt` is a 64-bit address; `nasm -felf64` would make sense for that.  Although addresses are little-endian, so the valuable bytes are the first 4.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it. It is not meant to be bootloader, but rather a snippet from the book of `how to get to protected mode`, which may - as you said - suggest bootloader, but is not. And the second - I have tried to compile with `felf64` flag, but then : `instruction not supported in 64-bit mode`, So I supposed, it is not able to in long mode.

Comment: So maybe, I am not even able to execute the program (trying to get to protected mode, but being already in one). So you are right, it does not make sense to even compile it, but still there are theoretical question in my post (about global descriptor table and `align` directive) to be answered.

Comment: @Pater Cordes, what is in `rax`? before setting the bit in `cr0`? I did not `mov`ed eny data in `rax` before that. So did I get some bits in `rax` from the `lgdt` ?

Comment: Ok, well regardless, you don't need to "obtain privileges".  A bootloader that includes this snippet would be one that's designed to start in real mode.  Any protected mode "kernel" that would run code in ring 3 doesn't typically provide an interface for letting that code raise itself to ring 0; it provides system calls to actually do stuff.  If you're prepared to let some code do arbitrary stuff, you might as well let it run in ring 0 in the first place. TL:DR: there isn't a "raise my privilege level" instruction.  (the privilege level is the low 2 bits of CS, so you change it via a far jmp.)

Comment: EAX is the low 32 bits of RAX.

Comment: I meant, what is the relation between RAX and LGDT. (before RAX is used after LGDT)

Comment: There isn't any.  Read the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt doesn't mention EAX / RAX at all.  The value in RAX comes from this code setting EAX = CR0.

Comment: To fix the first error, change `lgdt cs:[_gdtr]` into `lgdt [cs:_gdtr]`.  Refer to the NASM manual for the correct syntax for memory operands (the error message refers to line 4, not line 5 as you claimed).

Comment: Oh is *that* why you thought you there was a privilege problem?  Privileged or not is a run-time thing, but `invalid combination of opcode and operands` is an assemble-time error.

Comment: @PeterCordes but how is meant (by author), the value 47? Here: `_gdtr: ;stores GDT's last entry index + GDT address
    dw 47 
    dq _gdt`. How is meant `last entry index` as 47, and then GDT address?

Comment: Read the manual for lgdt: it's the limit part of the limit:address operand. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt.  I'm not sure why 47 bytes makes sense as the table size, though; in what you've shown the table stops after 24 bytes (3 entries).

Comment: @PeterCordes I know (according to manual), there are tow values - base and limit. But what about the others? How they are set? Code descriptor consists of more info the these two (such as "default operand size", "granularity", "Available", "Descriptor Privilege Level", and so on), are those bits set by `sgdt` instead of `lgdt`?

Comment: The limit and pointer are loaded into the internal GDTR; the pointer part *points* to the table.  That's why the code uses a label for that.  They are *not* themselves a descriptor; they're a reference to the table of descriptors, a pointer+length.

Comment: @PeterCordes, in the book is mentioned, in today's 64-OSes are no more vastly used descriptors, and  all programs used flat memory with base 0x0. But that is true only once the OS is booted up. But before, - that is - in real mode, you -as programmer have to initialize GDT by something like the code above? So what would happen if OS would NOT init. the GDT, and you would have to manage memory on your own? Would it destroy (or lost completely) virtual memory mechanism? (In other words, how much does Virtual memory RELY on GDT?)

Comment: Without a GDT you couldn't jump to a 64-bit code segment.  You literally *need* a GDT for 64-bit mode.  Read the manual about how x86 works, and/or osdev wiki:  https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table, and https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial, and https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64#How_do_I_enable_Long_Mode_.3F